# Build Error : Ice cream sandwich emulator on Ubuntu

Tags: android, build, emulation, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am trying to build ice cream sandwich emulator on Ubuntu Linux.

Getting following error :

```
host C++: libGLcommon <= development/tools/emulator/opengl/host/libs/
Translator/GLcommon/GLDispatch.cpp

development/tools/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLcommon/
GLDispatch.cpp:22:20: error: GL/glx.h: No such file or directory

development/tools/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLcommon/
GLDispatch.cpp: In function ‘void (* getGLFuncAddress(const char*))
()’:

development/tools/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLcommon/
GLDispatch.cpp:35: error: ‘glXGetProcAddress’ was not declared in this
scope

make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/
libGLcommon_intermediates/GLDispatch.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 7):

Looks like you're missing the `glx.h` file. This is provided by several packages, one of which you'll need to install. I'm pretty sure the one you want is `mesa-common-dev`.

Answer (score 0):

On Fedora 16, you need to install mesa-libGL-devel pacakge.

Answer (score 0):

GO to http://packages.debian.org/fi/sid/mesa-common-dev
and download package you want then use command sudo dpkg -i **.dev